# Feather js , return data that matches the query params

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, feathersjs

I only wanted to return result or true if all the query params matches. Any idea with that ? should I use where query ? Thanks. All in query params must be true to return a result , why current code does not do that.

## Code snippet

```
return from(this.feathers.service('feedback-requests').find<FeedbackRequest>({
      query: {
        formId: data.map(form => form.formId),
        respondentId: data.map(respondent => respondent.respondentId),
        recipientId: data.map(recipient => recipient.recipientId),
        periodStartDate:  { $in: data.map(startDate => startDate.periodStartDate)},
        periodEndDate: { $in: data.map(endDate => endDate.periodEndDate)},
      }
    }))
```

Comment: Could you clarify the context surrounding this query a bit more?

Comment: @naiveai what do you mean ?